# How can i display table admin grid to module

Tags: database, ubuntu

ref.like this >>

from this [image]

to this [image]

Comment: Please share your module files and also provide your table structure so that we can better understand your requirements.

Answer (score 0):

You have to do the following things.

1. Create Model into your custom extension.
2. Create Grid into extension and provided functionality of add, update and delete options into grid.
3. Now Using the Model which you created into step-1, fetch the collection of record and display according to your requirements.